# IBM Mobilefirst foundation 6.3 - Image caching solution

Tags: cordova, caching, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to find the best way to cache images on my Mobilefirst foundation app, my attempts to use any technique that involves Cordova plugins (Mainly File and File-Transfer plugins) has failed due to inability to install Cordova plugins.

Is there a way to install Cordova plugins work on MobileFirst app? If not is there an alternative way to cache images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova CLI is not supported at this time, so there is no easy way to integrate existing Cordova plug-ins. However there are many questions on this same issue with procedures to follow.

Another thing you can use is [IBM MobileFirst Platform JSONStore](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html) - encode the image to base64 and then save that data in the store. When you need it, decode the string and use it where required.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking for a way to add 3rd party plugins to MobileFirst (pending a feature release) I've posted an unofficial how-to on Stack Overflow @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141973/1311413. Essentially I create a Cordova project, add the plugins and then merge the plugin files from MobileFirst with those from the Cordova project.