# vuforia SDK for an IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, vuforia

I need to implement a few vuforia functionalities in an IBM MobileFirst existing project.

However I see that vuforia has provided SDKs only for android, iOS, UWP and unity.

How do I integrate vuforia SDK into my existing IBM MobileFirst project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobileFirst enables you to create either Hybrid (Web) apps ala Cordova, or native apps. However the end result is a Native project like any other.

So once you've generated your Xcode project in MobileFirst Studio (assuming you're using MobileFirst 7.1 and below), you can simply continue with the integration steps as supplied by Vuforia. They need not supply any special integration tools for IBM MobileFirst.

Comment: So in order to add vuforia functionality we need to generate xcode /Android  project from mobile first and then specifically add those vuforia functionality separately?

Comment: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/02_03_Previewing_your_application_on_Android.pdf but for android we can directly deploy from inside worklight environment.

Comment: Is there an additional question you're asking here?

Comment: hi the mobilefirst versions used for parent app are V6.1 for android and V7.1 for iOS.

However I saw on another post in stackoverflow that cordova plugin not supported for V6.1 http://stackoverflow.com/a/23705066/4794952 So how do I go about adding Vuforia for IBM worklight v6.1 ?